# JUnit setUp gets invoked TWO times with one test and messing up Powermock expectNew

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock, powermock

Very strange behaviour in my test.

```
  public class MyTestclass {
     @Before
     void setUp(){
        //do some setup, but hu i get called twice
        //here i do some try catch thing to get the stacktrace...
     }

     void testOnlyOneTest(){
        //make the testing, i get called only once
     }

     @After
     void tearDown(){
        //do some destroy things,... i get called twice too
     }
  }
```

StackTrace:

```
  1)
  MyTestClassTest.setUp() line: 85          
  NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
  NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
  DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25         
  Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597        
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).runBefores() line: 129                
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(Runnable) line: 93 
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(Method, Object, Runnable) line: 294               
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(Runnable) line: 282               
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).runTest() line: 84          
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).run() line: 49   
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(Method, RunNotifier) line: 207  
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(RunNotifier) line: 146   
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run() line: 120         
  ClassRoadie.runUnprotected() line: 34 
  ClassRoadie.runProtected() line: 44       
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(RunNotifier) line: 118      
  JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(RunNotifier) line: 102              
  PowerMockRunner(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner).run(RunNotifier) line: 53   
  JUnit4TestClassReference(JUnit4TestReference).run(TestExecution) line: 46  
  TestExecution.run(ITestReference[]) line: 38    
  RemoteTestRunner.runTests(String[], String, TestExecution) line: 467 
  RemoteTestRunner.runTests(TestExecution) line: 683 
  RemoteTestRunner.run() line: 390         
  RemoteTestRunner.main(String[]) line: 197       

  2)
  MyTestClassTest.setUp() line: 85          
  NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
  NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
  DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25         
  Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597        
  WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(Object, Method, Object...) line: 2014           
  WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(Object, Class<?>, String, Object...) line: 885  
  WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(Object, String, Object...) line: 713            
  Whitebox.invokeMethod(Object, String, Object...) line: 401     
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod() line: 305         
  MethodRoadie$2.run() line: 86                
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(Runnable) line: 94 
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(Method, Object, Runnable) line: 294               
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(Runnable) line: 282               
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).runTest() line: 84          
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner(MethodRoadie).run() line: 49   
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(Method, RunNotifier) line: 207  
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(RunNotifier) line: 146   
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run() line: 120         
  ClassRoadie.runUnprotected() line: 34 
  ClassRoadie.runProtected() line: 44       
  PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(RunNotifier) line: 118      
  JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(RunNotifier) line: 102              
  PowerMockRunner(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner).run(RunNotifier) line: 53   
  JUnit4TestClassReference(JUnit4TestReference).run(TestExecution) line: 46  
  TestExecution.run(ITestReference[]) line: 38    
  RemoteTestRunner.runTests(String[], String, TestExecution) line: 467 
  RemoteTestRunner.runTests(TestExecution) line: 683 
  RemoteTestRunner.run() line: 390         
  RemoteTestRunner.main(String[]) line: 197
```

Any ideas why my setUp gets called twice?

I do some mocking in the setUp and after a verify i get the expect 2 times called 1 times, thing so my tests fail.

i am using powermock 1.4.8, junit 4.4, and the easymock framework

Comment: Try to rename the setup and teardown methods, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Peter ty, but i tried that already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your class extend TestCase?  It doesn't appear to in the example but I'm just trying to think what *could* be causing this.  If it did then it would ignore the annotations and consider every method that starts with the word **test** as a test case causing you to have possibly more tests than you think.

Comment: damn you are good ;) yes you are right my testclass extends from my test super class in my project and that one extends from TestCase... and that beast executed it test**** methodes and the powermock executed @Test annotated tests.... damn you are good! ty :D

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) instead of [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html). [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) gets run before each method annotated with [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html), whereas [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) only runs once before all [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) methods.

Comment: That may work but I think the concern is the fact that there is only one method annotated with @Test.

Comment: Now that you mention that how are any tests getting run since there are no `@Test` annotated methods? A quick test shows that JUnit4 only runs methods with that annotation, so maybe PowerMock is doing it?  I wonder if that could be the root of the problem here.

Comment: @Pace yes that is exactly my problem

Comment: i think powermock is doing sth. but i can't figure out what, if you look into the stacktraces most of them are the same, but in the whiteboximpl is makeing me crazy i can't find the problem there...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make the setup method as "static".
Referring to this answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978702/964446

you cannot do both extends TestCase and use annotations, as they use different runners.
So when JUnit sees **extends TestCase** it will most probably use the old runner, where-in the **@Test annotation will be overlooked**.

You can simple make the setup method as static without extending the TestCase and use @Test annotations, this should work as per JUnit4

Comment: This indeed is a good answer. I even like it a bit more than the accepted one.
It just is not quite as readable - a few more linebreaks at the right place and formattings applied would help.